# Java - Runnable, lambda function, and methods of class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm quite new with Java (studied on University but was version 2).
Now I've developed an application that downloads files from s3 in parallel. I've used `ExecutorService` and `Runnable` to download multiple files in parallel in this way:

```
public class DownloaderController {
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    private ExecutorService fixedPool;
    private TransferManager dlManager;
    private List<MultipleFileDownload> downloads = new ArrayList<>();
    public DownloaderController() {
        checkForNewWork();
    }
    public void checkForNewWork(){
        Provider1 provider = new Provider1();
        fixedPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        List<Download> providedDownloadList = provider.toBeDownloaded();
            for (Download temp : providedDownloadList) {
                if (!downloadData.contains(temp)) {
                    fixedPool.submit(download.downloadCompletedHandler(s3Client));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void printToTextArea(String msg){
        Date now = new Date();
        if ( !DateUtils.isSameDay(this.lastLogged, now)){
            this._doLogRotate();
        }
        this.lastLogged = now;
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss");
        String output = "[ " + ft.format(now) + " ] " + msg + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //this is a FXML object
            statusTextArea.appendText(output);
        });
    }
}

public class Provider1 implements downloadProvider {

}

public class Download {
    abstract Runnable downloadCompletedHandler(AmazonS3 s3Client);
}

public class DownloadProvider1 extends Download {
    @Override
    public Runnable downloadCompletedHandler(AmazonS3 s3Client){
        Runnable downloadwork = () -> {
            ObjectListing list = s3Client.listObjects(this.bucket,this.getFolder());
            List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = list.getObjectSummaries();
            AtomicLong workSize = new AtomicLong(0);
            List<DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            objects.forEach(obj -> {
                workSize.getAndAdd(obj.getSize());
                keys.add((new DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion(obj.getKey())));
            });
            MultipleFileDownload fileDownload = dlManager.downloadDirectory("myBucket","folder","outputDirectory");
            try {
                fileDownload.waitForCompletion();
            } catch (Exception e){
                printToTextArea("Exception while download from AmazonS3");
            }   
        };
        return downloadwork;
    }
}
```

In the downloadController i call every minute a function that adds some Download objects to a List that contains folders that has to be downloaded from s3. when a new Download is added it's also added to ExecutorService pool. The Download object returns the code that has to be executed to download the folder from s3 and what to do when it's download is finished.
My problem is, what is the best way to communicate between the Runnable and the DownloadController ?

Comment: What is `caller`?

Comment: This code has some syntax errors. Could you please provide error free and executable code? Also, the call to `printToTextArea()` seems correct. I ain't getting the question correctly.

Comment: Why do you think what you've already got isn't the "best"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make entirely clear what the goal is. From what I understand, I would have done it something like this:

```
public class Download {
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    public Download(AmazonS2 client) { s3Client = client; }
    public void run() { // perform download }
}
```

That class does nothing but download the file (cfg Separation of Concern) and is a `Runnable`. You can do `executorService.submit(new Download(client))` and the download will be finished eventually; also, you can test it without being called concurrently.

Now, you want a callback method for logging it being finished.

```
public class LoggingCallback {
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}
```

Also a `Runnable` (the method doesn't have to be `run()`).

And, to make sure it's triggered one after the other, maybe

```
class OneAfterTheOther {
    private Runnable first;
    private Runnable second;
    public OneAfterTheOther(Runnable r1, Runnable r2) {
        first = r1; second = r2;
    }
    public void run() { first.run(); second.run(); }
}
```

which if submitted like this

```
Download dl = new Download(client);
Logger l = new LoggingCallback();
executorService.submit(new OneAfterTheOther(dl::run, l::log));
```

will do what I think you're trying to do.